# C++ - constructors being used twice for the same class

Tags: c++, oop, constructor

I have just started learning C++, and I came across the following code [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-heap/).

```
// A C++ program to demonstrate common Binary Heap Operations
#include<iostream>
#include<climits>
using namespace std;

// Prototype of a utility function to swap two integers
void swap(int *x, int *y);

// A class for Min Heap
class MinHeap
{
    int *harr; // pointer to array of elements in heap
    int capacity; // maximum possible size of min heap
    int heap_size; // Current number of elements in min heap
public:
    // Constructor
    MinHeap(int capacity);

    // to heapify a subtree with the root at given index
    void MinHeapify(int );

    int parent(int i) { return (i-1)/2; }

    // to get index of left child of node at index i
    int left(int i) { return (2*i + 1); }

    // to get index of right child of node at index i
    int right(int i) { return (2*i + 2); }

    // to extract the root which is the minimum element
    int extractMin();

    // Decreases key value of key at index i to new_val
    void decreaseKey(int i, int new_val);

    // Returns the minimum key (key at root) from min heap
    int getMin() { return harr[0]; }

    // Deletes a key stored at index i
    void deleteKey(int i);

    // Inserts a new key 'k'
    void insertKey(int k);
};

// Constructor: Builds a heap from a given array a[] of given size
MinHeap::MinHeap(int cap)
{
    heap_size = 0;
    capacity = cap;
    harr = new int[cap];
}
```

My doubt is that why are there two constructors for the same class?

```
public:
    // Constructor
    MinHeap(int capacity);
```

and

```
// Constructor: Builds a heap from a given array a[] of given size
MinHeap::MinHeap(int cap)
{
    heap_size = 0;
    capacity = cap;
    harr = new int[cap];
}
```

Is there a specific reason why the code is written in this particular way rather creating a single constructor at the beginning like so:

```
public:
    // Constructor
    MinHeap(int capacity, int* harr, int heap_size);
```

Moreover, is the constructor that is used at the end of the original code an another 'type' of constructor that serves a particular purpose?

Could someone also explain in detail what does the following line do:

```
MinHeap::MinHeap(int cap){}
```

Comment: There is only one constructor. first one is declaration and another one is definition.

Comment: **Do not** ask multiple questions inside a question.

Comment: One is the declaration, the other is the implementation. The declaration is commonly placed in a header file, the implementation is commonly placed in a separate source file that includes the header file

Comment: So am I expected to create 4 different questions if I have a doubt in a piece of code? @user202729

Comment: @SunitGautam, If you have four researched questions, then yes. Future visitors come here for the question in the title and the site design around one accepted answer becomes rather useless if each answer addresses a different question. I can tell you that you will find answers for all of these in good introductory material, though.

Comment: @SunitGautam Yes. [so] does not just provide help for **you** (the OP), also for future readers. Those future readers don't want to read the 3 other questions and their answers (which are unrelated to their problem) on the same page.

Comment: Remember to provide only a [mcve], instead of the whole code, if possible.

Comment: "Teach me the meaning of basic C++" such as that a declaration and defnition are the same function, isn't really suitable for StackOverflow.

Comment: @Sunit Gautam - Ehh, *yes*. If you have 4 questions you should ask 4 questions. Of course.

Answer (score 2):

> My doubt is that why are there two constructors for the same class?

There is *only one* constructor here.

The one is the *declaration* and the other one is the *definition*. Notice how the definition/implementation of the constructor is placed outside the class. That's why the author uses the scope resolution operator, with the name of the class preceding it (`MinHeap::`).

> Is there a specific reason why the code is written in this particular way rather creating a single constructor at the beginning like so

As answered above, there is a single constructor in that code. The constructor you mention is a different one, with a new prototype, an overload of the constructor.

> Moreover, is the constructor that is used at the end of the original code an another 'type' of constructor that serves a particular purpose?

It's just the implementation of the constructor, as mentioned in the first answer.

> Could someone also explain in detail what does the following line do: `MinHeap::MinHeap(int cap){}`?

There is no such code in the code posted above. In any case, this would be the implementation of a constructor for a class named `MinHeap`, which takes one argument of type `int`, called `cap`, and does nothing (its body is empty).

Please note that this is an implementation (it has a body). Moreover, it is defined outside the class `MinHeap`. It could be placed in either a header or a source file.

It is important to understand that this constructor is an implementation, while this:

```
MinHeap(int cap);
```

is just a definition (notice the absence of a body).